# Using exercise package correctly

Tags: exercises

Please correct my code as necessary.  It is not compiling due to

```
! Package exercise Error: You don't respect the hierarchy of questions.

See the exercise package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \begin{Question}W
                      hat is the symbol for copper?\end{Question}
?
```

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}
\section{Naming of Chemical Compounds - A ``DIY'' Tutorial}

\begin{Exercise}[title=DIY]\end{Exercise}
\begin{ExePart}Question 1\end{ExePart}
\begin{Question}What is the symbol for copper?\end{Question}
\begin{Answer}\ce{Cu}\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

It could be that I've missed something but the documentation does not even provide an example of the package's usage.

Comment: I haven't seen the documentation (as the error suggests to do), but I'm *supposing* that the `Exercise` environment should probably end after the `Answer` environment... that would make more sense to me. Just a guess though...

Comment: I thought they should be nested at first too but that results in an error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{list} on input line 13 ended by \end{Question}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 ...at is the symbol for copper?\end{Question}
                                                  
? `  Any ideas?

Comment: Just playing with it... the package doesn't seem very robust, and the doc doesn't really help...

Comment: I agree, the documentation is really lacking in instructive value; at first it seemed polished and comprehensive but after reading for half an hour I'm not much wiser for it...  Package authors are not doing justice to their packages if documention doesn't actually instruct in its usage, explicitly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to get it to work using the ExerciseList environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}
\section{Naming of Chemical Compounds - A ``DIY'' Tutorial}

\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise[title=DIY]
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{What is the symbol for copper?}
  \Answer{\ce{Cu}}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

**Use of \ExePart or redefinition of \QuestionNB**

That said, you shouldn't need the `\ExePart` just to print "Question 1". It might be better to redefine `\QuestionNB` instead, like this:

```
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{Question~\arabic{Question}.\ }
```

*Theorically*, that should do what you want to achieve, although in practice, it's kind of a mess. I feel the reason is that the label is hardcoded in the package, and without a variable. This can however be "fixed" by resetting `\QuestionIndent`:

```
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{7em}
```

So your example becomes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}
\section{Naming of Chemical Compounds - A ``DIY'' Tutorial}

\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{Question~\arabic{Question}.\ }
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{7em}

\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise[title=DIY]
  \Question{What is the symbol for copper?}
  \Answer{\ce{Cu}}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

which works for me (although I would personally find it nicer to put questions on the next line -- note: I'm not using the `mhchem` package):

[image: exercise_example]

After playing a bit with more Questions/Answers, I do think it's missing a linebreak somewhere:

[image: more questions]

I'm also not very sure of the spacing: answers end up being closer to the next question than to the question they relate to...

**Exercise title**

In fact, it seems the problem with the linebreak comes from the fact that you're using `\Exercise[title=DIY]` instead of simply `\Exercise{DIY}`, which defines the exercise name. When I change this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}
\section{Naming of Chemical Compounds - A ``DIY'' Tutorial}

\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{Question~\arabic{Question}.\ }
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{7em}

\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise{DIY}
  \Question{What is the symbol for copper?}
  \Answer{\ce{Cu}}
  \Question{What is the symbol for aluminum?}
  \Answer{\ce{Al}}
  \Question{What is the symbol for iron?}
  \Answer{\ce{Fe}}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

I get a linebreak:

[image: proper_linebreaks]

and it is not necessary anymore to redefine `\QuestionIndent`:

[image: without redefining QuestionIndent]

Comment: Great! :)  Just one small problem: did you notice the Question counter isnt advancing; it's just staying on 1?  Shouldn't it automatically advance?  Do you know how to fix this?  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 10):

`\Question` is a command, not environment. That's why you get the errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}


\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}
\section{Naming of Chemical Compounds - A ``DIY'' Tutorial}



\begin{Exercise}[title=DIY,label=E1]
\ExePart[name=simple]
\Question{What is the symbol for copper?}\label{Q1}
\Question{What is the symbol for oxygen?}\label{Q2}

\ExePart[name=difficult]
\Question{What 42?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}[ref=E1]\ref{Q1}. Cu  \quad\ref{Q2}. O \end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the answers immediately follow their respective questions, rather than appear all at once at the end?  That is, so you get Q1, A1, Q2, A2, ... etc.

Answer (score 2):

Answers must be out of the list. This way, counters work fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}


\usepackage[lastexercise, answerdelayed]{exercise}


\begin{document}
\section{Naming of Chemical Compounds - A ``DIY'' Tutorial}


\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise[title=DIY, label=E1]
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{What is the symbol for copper?}
  \Question{What is the symbol for iron?}
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{What is the symbol for copper?}
  \Question{What is the symbol for iron?}

  \Exercise[title=DIY, label=E2]
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{What is the symbol for oxigen?}
  \Question{What is the symbol for hidrogen?}
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{What is the symbol for oxigen?}
  \Question{What is the symbol for hidrogen?}



\end{ExerciseList}



  \begin{Answer}[ref=E1]
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{Cu}
  \Question{Fe}     
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{Cu}
  \Question{Fe}     
  \end{Answer}

  \begin{Answer}[ref=E2]
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{O}
  \Question{H}      
  \ExePart{Question 1}
  \Question{O}
  \Question{H}      
  \end{Answer}


\paragraph*{ Solutions:}   Now, let's see te solutions
\shipoutAnswer 
\end{document}
```